# How to get object from ArrayList in android java

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList` in my Adapter. When an item is clicked, I want to construct a new `Intent` using an object from the `ArrayList`. How do I get the Object out of the list?

Below is snippet of my onClick:

```
public class zlecenia extends Activity {

    ListView listview;
    ArrayList myList = new ArrayList();

    String[] desc = new String[]{
            "Desc 1", "Desc 2", "Desc 3", "Desc 4",
            "Desc 5", "Desc 6", "Desc 7", "Desc 8"
    };
    String[] data = new String[]{
            "20:11", "", "11:25", "", "15:11", "11:25", "15:11", "11:25"
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.zlecenia);

        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        for (int i = 0; i < title.length; i++) {
            ListData ld = new ListData();
            ld.setDescription(desc[i]);
            ld.setData(data[i]);
            myList.add(ld);
        }

        listview.setAdapter(new MyBaseAdapter(this, myList));

        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {

                // What here?

            }

        });

    }

}


public class ListData {

    String Description;
    String title;
    String data;

    public String getDescription() {
        return Description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        Description = description;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

}
```

Comment: Of what type is `myList` ?

Comment: myList is of the type ArrayList

Comment: `ArrayList<what?>` ?

Comment: ArrayList myList = new ArrayList();

Comment: What type of objects do you store in this arrayList ?

Comment: so, you have a list, you have the position of the item clicked. what else do you need?

Comment: I nedded values from a object ArrayList. @Sparta helped me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
ArrayList myList = new ArrayList();
```

to

```
ArrayList<ListData> myList = new ArrayList<ListData>();
```

And use this:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
    // The 'position' argument represents the index of the clicked listview item
    ListData listdata = myList.get(position);
    // Do whatever you want with your listData item
}
```

Comment: @SeaDog you're welcome. Please upvote the answer, I don't get why it was downvoted.

Comment: I have yet one question. Which means exactly this sequence: ArrayList<ListData> myList = new ArrayList<ListData>();? When I removed <ListData> this: ListData listdata = myList.get(position); is marked on red but when I add: ListData listdata = (ListData) myList.get(position); the application works. I can not find explanation.

Comment: Check this http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/util/arraylist/arraylist-in-java-example-how-to-use-arraylist/

Comment: OK, so if I have an another class which is ListData, is it my constructor?

Comment: You need to specify the type of items that your arraylist will contain while instantiating it.

Comment: I corrected my question. I understand. For example: if I have a class ListData, which return a values in a loop, so which a type is this object? I understand that ArrayList keep an objects in cells and in particular objects are a some data? ListData ld = new ListData(); this is create new object and this: myList.add(ld); added this object to ArrayList. Is it true?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98333/discussion-between-sparta-and-seadog).

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayList`s (as well as most implementations of `List`) are supposed to be told what type of object they contains, in your case that is `ListData`, so you should change your construction of the list `ArrayList myList = new ArrayList();` to `ArrayList<ListData> myList = new ArrayList<>();`

All you have to do now, is change `Array object = (Array) myList.get(position);` to be `ListData myData = myList.get(positiion);`. Then you can do whatever you need to with your `ListData`

I suggest you read the [`ArrayList`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html) documentation (and the [java one](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html))

Comment: I can receive a index, but I can't receive a data from myList

Comment: You can't recieve data as in it always returns `null`? what do you mean? Maybe post a more complete code sample (how you create the list, and how you add things to it would help)

Answer (score 0):

you can call
 ListData listdata = myList.get(position);

on the basis of position we can fetch the object from arraylist